# How do you make map styles NOT appear in a legend?

Tags: geoserver, sld, legend, style

I am using GeoServer to serve up OSM data. I am making use of the GetLegendGraphic command, but I do not want some of my styles to appear in the legend (for example, the styles that are ONLY for text labels should not get a line).

Is there any way to specify that a style NOT appear in a legend?

Comment: In case it helps the use-case any, here is the situation. Using the OSM styles, there are styles defined for each road type for multiple scales [ex. 0-10k, 10k-40k, 40k-100k]. There are separate rules for the text labels on those roads for two scales [0-20k, 20k-50k]. The un-usable solution to this is to basically multiply those two and merge them [0-10k, 10k-20k, 20k-40k, 40k-50k], but that does not make the code maintainable and adds a lot of redundancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's now possible to exclude a rule from the Legend Graphic, see https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-selection.html.

Just add

```
<VendorOption name="inclusion">mapOnly</VendorOption>
```

to your rule.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to hide a rule from the GetLegendGraphics call.
The SLD standard does not provide a way either, so someone would have to come up with an extension to the standard and then code to implement it at the Geotools and GeoServer level.

Answer (score 3):

did you check GetLegendGraphic parameters in [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html). i didnt try something about your needs but i have used SCALE parameter eliminating internal rules that are out-of-scope.

```
&SCALE= 10000
```

maybe defining some rules give you what you want...

> Rule of style to produce legend graphic for, if applicable. In the
>   case that a style has multiple rules but no specific rule is selected,
>   then the map server is obligated to produce a graphic that is
>   representative of all of the rules of the style.

and you can check out [this](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/problems-with-legends-td3797998.html) too..

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I was familiar with scale, but not with the rule command. Still, it doesn't quite fix the problem [unless, I guess, we have a GetLegendGraphic call for each of the non-text styles]. I'm pretty sure this is one of those things that just isn't supported.